# .renderTitle(false) is not working on linechart DC.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, dc.js

I have some DC.js charts, I added a tooltip with d3-tip, so I needed to disable .title, use .renderTitle (false) and works well with bar charts and a GeoJson map, but when I use it in Linechart does not work. Is it a DC.js or d3-tip bug?

Comment: It works for me, in a quick test. I think you need to call it before first rendering the chart: calling `.renderTitle(false)` will not remove any existing tooltips. Is that the problem?

Comment: https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/line.html

In this example, when u put the mouse on the dot shows a tooltip, the .renderTitle (false) property should disable that, but it does not work on the linechart.

Comment: Yes exactly. I ran that example, stuck a breakpoint before `chart.render()` called `chart.renderTitle(false)` in the debugger, and voila, no titles.

Comment: i do that and doesn't work for me, What I can be doing wrong?

lineChart.renderTitle(false);

Comment: I don't know and without an example it's hard for me to guess. Are you sure you are doing this before the chart is **first** rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, but you have to call it before the chart is rendered, because it will not affect an existing chart. (And redraw won't remove any existing titles.)

Here is a fiddle demo, based on the [Line Chart Example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/line.html). The important part is calling

```
chart.renderTitle(false);
```

before

```
chart.render();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1rafgm40/2/

Comment: Maybe it's the version? I'm using 1.6.0

Comment: Aha, why didn't I think of that. Yes, you should really upgrade to 2.0 if you can. It looks like [this feature was implemented for line charts in Dec 2013](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/commit/488fe29e), after 1.6 was released. (There's a gap in the release notes between 1.6 and 2.0 beta 1.)

Comment: With dc.js 2.0 what version of d3 and crossfilter should I use?

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about the crossfilter version. d3 should be 3.5.* (4.* is not supported yet)

Comment: Thank you! I have another question but it will be for another question